# Update, set + 90 where ... (query updates wrong values)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlplus

this is part of a homework assignment - just to let you guys know. I have created a bunch of tables and filled them with values, and to end off the paper I would have to answer some questions besides giving out my source code.
The question is:

Update the BOOK_COPY table as follows.  Set the date_due as the sum of date_out + [90 for FACULTY, 30 for STUDENT, 40 FOR GUEST], using 3 separate update commands
Show the update commands.  After the update, show the following attributes of BOOK_COPY: bookid, copy_num, date_out, date_due for  book copies checked out only.  ORDER your listing by bookid, copy_num.

So far I have tried with a lot of different solutions as I can't make it work. I'm pretty sure I'll have to use a nested subquery, but something in my syntax is wrong. I have also tried with a join but that gave an even worse result lol. With the subquery I can get it to update the BOOK_COPY table but it updates other rows than just the ones of the faculty members. If I make out how to change the due_date for the faculty members, it of course won't be a problem to do it for the other two types.

Here are my two best bets so far:

```
update BOOK_COPY
set DATE_DUE = DATE_OUT + 90 
where OUT_TO_CID
(select CID from CUSTOMER
where CATEGORY = 'Faculty');

or

update BOOK_COPY
set DATE_DUE = DATE_OUT + 90
where BOOK_COPY.OUT_TO_CID = CUSTOMER.CID and CUSTOMER.CATEGORY =
'Faculty';
```

Book_copy table:

```
create table BOOK_COPY
(Copy_Num number(5),
Bookid  number(5),
out_to_CID number(6),
Date_Out date,
Date_Due date,
Held_Until date,
held_for_CID number(6),
CONSTRAINT PKCOPY PRIMARY KEY (Copy_Num,Bookid),
CONSTRAINT FKCID FOREIGN KEY (out_to_CID) references CUSTOMER (CID),
CONSTRAINT FKHeld FOREIGN KEY (held_for_CID) references CUSTOMER (CID),
CONSTRAINT FKBookid FOREIGN KEY (Bookid) references BOOK (Bookid));
```

Customer table:

```
create table CUSTOMER
(CID number(6),
First_Name varchar2(12),
Last_Name varchar2(12),
Category varchar2(7),
Balance_Due number(4,2),
SponsorID number(6),
CONSTRAINT pkCID PRIMARY KEY (CID),
CONSTRAINT fkCUSTOMER foreign key (sponsorID) references customer);
```

Please let me know if something about my post is against the rules. Thanks for reading it to the end ;-)

Comment: "something in my syntax is wrong" is not a problem description. What specific error are you getting? (Also, as a note: a nested subquery isn't what you need. You need to look at a CASE statement.) Also, you should [edit] your question to make the title more related to the problem you're having. Oracle and SQLPlus are made clear in your tags, so you have absolutely zero meaningful content in the question title. Your subject should be specific about the question you are asking or the problem you're experiencing, and should have meaning when found in a search result by someone in tthe future.

Comment: Thank you for the tips on how to improve the understanding of my posts, Ken. I have already received the help I needed, but I will correct the title as you requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
You're missing the IN clause

```
update book_copy
set DATE_DUE = DATE_OUT +90    
where OUT_TO_CID IN
(select CID
from CUSTOMER where CATEGORY ='Faculty');
```